# Representation of $G$ with dimension larger than $\lvert G \rvert$ is reducible？

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Suppose a finite group $G$ has order smaller than the dimension of a vector space $V$ over any field, how to prove that the representation of $G$ on $V$ is reducible？

Comment: See part 1 of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14514/how-big-can-the-irreps-of-a-finite-group-be-over-an-arbitrary-field/14516#14516

Answer (score 3):

$\rho : G \to \text{End}(V)$ is a representation, $V$ is a $K$-vector space. Take a non-zero vector $v \in V$ and let $$W = \text{span}(\rho(g_1)v,\rho(g_2)v,\ldots) = \{ \sum_{g \in G} a_g\,\rho(g) v, a_g \in K\}$$

Then $$\rho(h) (\sum_{g \in G} a_g\,\rho(g) v) = \sum_{g \in G} a_g\,\rho(hg) v=\sum_{g \in G} a_{h^{-1}g}\,\rho(g) v \in W$$

Thus $W$ is a $\rho$ invariant subspace and $\rho|_W : G \to \text{End}(W)$ is a sub-representation, $\dim(W) \le |G|$

($\rho|_W(g)=P \rho(g) P$ where $P$ is the orthogonal projection $V \to W$)

Answer (score 1):

The following works over the complex numbers -- I'm not sure if there is an analogous result for arbitrary fields:

Let $Irr(G)$ be the set of all irreducible representations of $G$, then
$$|G| = \sum_{\rho \in Irr(G)} \deg(\rho)^2$$

(See for instance Corollary 4.4.5 of Benjamin Steinberg's [Representation Theory of Finite Groups](http://users.metu.edu.tr/sozkap/513-2013/Steinberg.pdf))

Comment: If a field $F$ is splitting filed for $FG$ then $$(\dim S)^2 \le \sum_{S\ \text{simple}} (\dim S)^2 = \dim FG/J(FG) \le \lvert G \rvert$$ by the Wedderburn theorem.

Comment: @Orat Do we need [Maschke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation#Reducibility) to obtain equality ?